# Laravel Passport : Users only have one token not many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

Laravel Passport has a very complex system for my app cause I think for this simple app it's very complex to have OAuth client's Id, Secret & ...
So I create a UserController myself to solve this complexity with these codes:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct(){
        $this->content = array();
    }
     public function login(){
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $this->content['token'] =  $user->createToken('URL APP')->accessToken;
        $status = 200;
    }
    else{
        $this->content['error'] = "Unauthorised";
         $status = 401;
    }
     return response()->json($this->content, $status);    
    }
}
```

but problem is every time user sign in get new tokens & old tokens won't expire & User with old tokens can send valid request (Its should be invalid I think).
Is there any way to config passport to users has one token or I should do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a problem with jwt tokens. But you can overcome this problem by making your own methods or by using some other libraries. "jwt-auth" is also a library for token and this also got the blacklist method you  can use to blacklist a token.

or you can make  a middleware in your routes and cache the token in redis or memcached database and save it against user_id and match it everytime with requests.